# Looking for Robot Framework Library or a good java library for automating mac gui

Tags: macos, automated-tests, robotframework

Is there any good robot framework library that exists for automating GUI on mac?

or any good java library? I googled and nothing came up very promising.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your are describing is an OSX version of Autoit.

Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485254/equivalent-of-autoit-for-mac-os-x) can you help out. I have not really looked into it, but I am not sure this will work with Robot Framework...